# Model association between Company, Employee, and department

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

I am working in Ruby on Rails 3. And trying to map out three models which mimic the data of a Company its employees and their respective departments.

In arrived at the following solution:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departments
  has_many :employees, through => :departments
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :employees
  has_one :department_description
end

class DepartmentDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
end
```

Is this the 'correct' way to associate these models?

Comment: There's no reason (given the context you've provided) why you should have a separate table/model just for the `Department`'s `:description`. Add that column to `Department` and get rid of the `has_one` relationship on `:department_description`

Comment: True I haven't added any context. But the case being the has_many :employees, through => :departments effectively makes the department-table (DB) a join table, where I the DepartmentDescription (name, email, etc.) will be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think your last response may explain why you are struggling to find a correct way to associate these models.

It seems that you see your Department merely as a join_table, and that may be due to the fact that you don't fully understand the has_many => :through construction and that it actually allows your Department to be a proper model with many attributes and methods in it, hence also a 'description' attribute.

To create a separate DepartmentDescription model is actually a waste of resource. Chad Fowler has a few good examples for :has_many => through and nested resources in his Rails Recipes... so check that out.